# Postgres pagination. Using the "Pagination" library. Works great for pagination for ALL records, BUT if I do a search I lose the search. And crash

Tags: postgresql, flask

Stack: Flask, Postgres and thousands of records. The "Flask-Pagination" library works great, looks cool, and lots of options. But documentation is not there. Once I do a "search" the pagination will not pass the search query back to Flask. And I crash.

Looking at the documentation, there must be a way to access and pass the search terms, but I'm not seeing it, and zero examples on line.

List of library attributes here: https://flask-paginate.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Example here. Search for Brain, you will get over 400+ responses but cannot get pass the first page if you want to pagination, 96 records at a time. Do a "Update" all and you can pagination through thousands of records.

Live example: https://www.hackingthevirus.com

Thanks, LOTS!

Answer (score -1):

Used sessions. Allows for saving of the "search" value across multiple pages.